# incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: string, methods, integer, java

so in the 4th method I'm trying to determine the winner but it says that the int cannot be converted to java.lang.String 
and yes i have to use different methods, and if you find anything else wrong with the code let me know , thank you

```
import java.util.Random;// importing the random class to generate random number 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;//importing the JOptionPane to use the pop up windows and menu
public class TiriBark 
{
  private static int ComputerWin =0; // 0 is for loss and 1 for win 
  private static int UserWins =0; // 0 is for loss and 1 for win 
  private static int tie=0; // if it's a tie the value will be 1 
  private static int Comp; // holds the value of the random number generated by the computer 
  private static int user; // holds users choice of rock papper or scissor 
  public static void main(String[] args) // main method 
  {
   Computer();
   user();
  }
  /**this method generated a random number between 1 and 3 
    *@return Comp 
    */
  public static int Computer()
  {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int Comp = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
    return Comp;}
  /**this method asked the user to enter his choice of rock paper or scissor 
    *@return user
    */
  public static int user (){
     String User = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1 for rock 2 for paper and 3 for scissor ");
    int user = Integer.parseInt(User);
    return user; }
  /** this method calculates and determines the winner and if possible a tie 
    *@return ComputerWin
    *@return UserWins 
    *@return tie
    */
  public static String resutls() {
    if ( user == Comp ) {
      tie =1; }
    if ( user==1 && Comp == 2){
      ComputerWin=1; }
    if ( user ==1 && Comp ==3){
      UserWins=1;}
    if ( user ==2 && Comp ==1 ){
      UserWins=1;}
    if ( user ==2 && Comp == 3 ){
      ComputerWin=1;}

    if ( user ==3 && Comp ==1) {
      ComputerWin=1; }

    if ( user ==3 && Comp ==2 ){
      UserWins=1;}
    return UserWins;
    return ComputerWin;
    return tie;

  }
}
```

Comment: All the values you return from `resutls()` are `int` values. I suggest making the method return type be `int`

Comment: Are you trying to return 3 values?

Comment: yes bradimus , but I"m guessing that's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this:

```
return UserWins;
return ComputerWin;
return tie;
```

you are generating dead code, because the function ends at the first return.
If you want to cast the **int** variable into **String** just do:

```
return UserWins + "";
```

Comment: should I be dividing this method into 3 other methods ?

Comment: `return Integer.toString(UserWins);` more clearly expresses the intent.

Comment: You are modifying three static variables  of the class.

Comment: so you can keep the function's logic and change return type to void

Comment: the variables will change and you don't have to return nothing

Answer (score 0):

UserWins is indeed an integer. To convert the integer to a String you can do:

```
String result = "" + UserWins;
return result;
```

This will automatically convert your integers to Strings. There are many other ways to do this same conversion.

Comment: `return Integer.toString(UserWins);` more clearly expresses the intent.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with your code is the three return statements at the end of the method in question.

```
public static String resutls() {
    if ( user == Comp ) {
      tie =1; }
    if ( user==1 && Comp == 2){
      ComputerWin=1; }
    if ( user ==1 && Comp ==3){
      UserWins=1;}
    if ( user ==2 && Comp ==1 ){
      UserWins=1;}
    if ( user ==2 && Comp == 3 ){
      ComputerWin=1;}

    if ( user ==3 && Comp ==1) {
      ComputerWin=1; }

    if ( user ==3 && Comp ==2 ){
      UserWins=1;}
    return UserWins;
    return ComputerWin;
    return tie;
```

With the way it is written here, the program will return `UserWins` no matter what just because it will be the next code after checking who won. What you want to do is put the return statements within you if statements. So what this will do is when the method is called, it will check the if statements and whichever one that is correct, the corresponding return statement will be executed. Try something like this:

```
if(user == Comp)
{
     return tie;
}
else if(user == 1 && Comp == 2)
{
     return ComputerWin;
}
```

For your String problem; my first question is do you need the method to return a String? The problem here is that the method declaration is: `public static String results()`. This must return a string, meaning your return statement has to be a String type. Changing it to type int should fix your problem.